# CSS3 flex-direction property lost effect in Chrome 21?

Tags: google-chrome, css, flexbox

I have update my Chrome to version 21. I have used flex property to defined some css style:

```
display: -webkit-flexbox;
-webkit-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

But I find all the lost its effect in the new version chrome, so I try change to :

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

the head 3 property have changed correctedly,
The last `-webkit-flex-direction` is still don't work like before, but the chrome the develop tool show the property is correct

demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/dPK5f/1/), I want to use the property make the `h1` order in column

How can I solve this problem?Or should add some property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Chrome 21 is the first version to use the [new flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) model.

Note: Chrome 29 and later do not use prefixes for flex properties.

I've written two implementations, based on your first example. My first demo uses the [original version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Flexbox#box-_implementation) of the flexbox specification, the second one uses the [latest version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Flexbox#flex-_implementation).
Here's a demo which shows both in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dPK5f/2/ <sup>(with flexible size: http://jsfiddle.net/dPK5f/3/)</sup>

```css
/* The properties are ordered to make it easier to compare them */
#old {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
#flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: Actually you don't solve my confuse about why the same property perform different in different version of Chrome...

Comment: @hh54188 That was not stated in your question. The answer to your confusion can be derived from my answer. At the top of MDN: ["This is an experimental technology. (..) Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is **subject to change in future version of browsers *as the spec changes***."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). And that's what happened: The spec changed, and Chrome followed the updated spec.