# How to write persistent CSS box rules?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773378/css3-flex-direction-property-lost-effect-in-chrome-21), developers of Chrome changed

`display: -webkit-box` to `display: -webkit-flexbox`

However when I test it now (v25.0.1364), I see it's again changed and look what we have:

[image: old and new implementation]

We again lost `display:-webkit-flex` and `-webkit-flex-direction:column` rule. 

 (black fonts mean they are not applicable)

Therefore, I want to write a bulletproof rule so it will work in anyway. But, if I write something like this:

```
<div id="box_container" class="horz_new horz_old"> <div>
```

it again fails because it accepts some `webkit-box` property as well as some `-webkit-flex` properties which makes some conflict between rules.

I've prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjZF9/) by including all needed.

Can anyone help me about this?
Or, maybe should I turn back to floated divs?

Comment: If you want bulletproof, avoid vendor extensions.  The whole point of vendor extensions is that they mark experimental features which are therefore likely to be changed.

Comment: Yeah... if you need bulletproof then stop using flexbox, it's way too new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old `-webkit-box-*` properties only apply (are pertinent) for containers that have `display: -webkit-box` on them. You should be able to mix the new (`display: flex`) and old flexbox (`display: box`) which much issue. Here's a great article on using both together: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

I've update your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/UjZF9/1/) with a few changes that gets everything working. Basically:

- `-webkit-flex-direction: row;` for horizontal layout (the default) and `-webkit-flex-direction: column;` for vertical layout.
- `stretch` is not a possible value for the `justify-content` property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/justify-content for possible values.
- You needed a `-webkit-flex:1` on your children (similar to`-webkit-box-flex:1`).

I have some nice playable demos on http://www.htmlfivecan.com/#11 to see how the different flexbox properties change the layout. Give it a try.